# ms sql table adding rows whenever level changes by more than 1 so that every row has difference of 1 in start_level and end_level

Tags: sql-server

(This is my first stack overflow question. So please let me know suggestions for posing a better question, if you cannot understand.)
I have a table of around 500 people(users) who are going up the stairs from floor x (0=x, max(y) = 50). A person can climb zero/one or many levels in a single go which corresponds to a single row of the table along with the time taken to do so in seconds.
I want to find average time taken to go from floor a to a+1 where a is any of the floor number. To do so I intend to divide every row of the mentioned table into rows which have start_level+1= end_level. Duration will be divided equally as shown in EXPECTED OUTPUT TABLE for user b.

```
GIVEN TABLE INPUT
start_level end_level   duration user
1           1           10        a
1           2           5         a
2           5           27        b
5           6           3         c

EXPECTED OUTPUT

start_level end_level   duration user
1           1           10       a
1           2           5        a
2           3           27/3     b
3           4           27/3     b
4           5           27/3     b
5           6           3        c
```

Note: level jumps are in integers only.
After getting expected output, I can simply create a column sum(duration)/count(distinct users) at a start_level level to get average time taken to get one floor above from each floor.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? What exactly is your question?

Comment: how do you arive to the value of end_level ? In test data end_level is 5 when start level is 2, at expected result end_level is 3 when start_level is 2

Comment: i have added required details. let me know if the question is still unclear. Thanks.

Comment: A suggestion, just to start: I would build a table or a CTE with counters from 0 to 50 and then join it with your given table, putting condition "on Counters.counter between yourtable.start_level and yourtable.end_level".

Comment: its a nice problem. you can edit and add some more explanation or some code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Numbers table to "create" the incremental steps. Here's my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE #floors
  (
     [start_level] INT,
     [end_level]   INT,
     [duration]    DECIMAL(10, 4),
     [user]        VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #floors
            ([start_level],
             [end_level],
             [duration],
             [user])
VALUES      (1,1,10,'a'),
            (1,2,5,'a'),
            (2,5,27,'b'),
            (5,6,3,'c')
```

Then, using a Numbers table and some LEFT JOIN/COALESCE logic:

```
-- Create a Numbers table
;WITH Numbers_CTE
     AS (SELECT TOP 50 [Number] = ROW_NUMBER()
                                    OVER(
                                      ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
         FROM   sys.columns)

SELECT [start_level] = COALESCE(n.[Number], f.[start_level]),
       [end_level] = COALESCE(n.[Number] + 1, f.[end_level]),
       [duration] = CASE
                      WHEN f.[end_level] = f.[start_level] THEN f.[duration]
                      ELSE f.[duration] / ( f.[end_level] - f.[start_level] )
                    END,
       f.[user]
FROM   #floors f
       LEFT JOIN Numbers_CTE n
              ON n.[Number] BETWEEN f.[start_level] AND f.[end_level]
                 AND f.[end_level] - f.[start_level] > 1
```

Here are the logical steps:

1. LEFT JOIN the Numbers table for cases where end_level >= start_level + 2 (this has the effect of giving us multiple rows - one for each incremental step)
2. new start_level =  If the LEFT JOIN "completes": take Number from the Numbers table, else: take the original start_level
3. new end_level =  If the LEFT JOIN "completes": take Number + 1, else: take the original end_level
4. new duration = If end_level = start_level: take the original duration (to avoid divide by 0), else: take the average duration over end_level - start_level